# NPM Install Error: ENPSYS -78 Symlink Function not Implemented

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, symlink, mkdir

when I try to install several npm packages locally I repeatedly get an ENOSYS -78 symlink "function not implemented" error. I'm relatively new to this so sorry if it's a basic question, but I haven't been able to figure it out by searching around.

my system: 
osx 10.13.6 ; 
node -> v11.0.0 & v.8.12.0 ; 
npm v.6.4.1 ; 
nvm v.0.33.11

Below are my error messages:

```
$ npm i iohook --save
npm WARN whatatest@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path ../mkdirp/bin/cmd.js
npm ERR! code ENOSYS
npm ERR! errno -78
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! ENOSYS: function not implemented, symlink '../mkdirp/bin/cmd.js' -> '/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/NYU/Senior/Semester 1/IRCAM/final/node-test/node_modules/.bin/mkdirp'
```

and when I try to install mkdirp I get a similar error...

```
$ npm i mkdirp --save
npm WARN whatatest@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path ../mkdirp/bin/cmd.js
npm ERR! code ENOSYS
npm ERR! errno -78
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! ENOSYS: function not implemented, symlink '../mkdirp/bin/cmd.js' -> '/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/NYU/Senior/Semester 1/IRCAM/final/node-test/node_modules/.bin/mkdirp'
```

Any advice is much appreciated :)

EDIT:
I was able to install mkdirp locally after I installed it globally. Trying to install iohook still returns the same error, globally or locally.

Comment: It looks like you're installing on a Google Drive mountpoint, which apparently doesn't support symbolic links. Not sure if this can be fixed, because NPM depends on a filesystem that supports symlinks.

Comment: Thank you Robert! I suspected this may be the issue and made sure all files were hosted locally before I posted, but copying everything to my documents folder fixes the issue...